# Iterate over 'DateTime' field and display only current and future objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `DateTime` field for displaying events, and would like to show only the events that are scheduled for today or in the future. I found [groupdate](https://rubygems.org/gems/groupdate/versions/2.5.2), which looks cool, but I was wondering if there is a gem-free way that would be the best for this particular use.

**index.html.rb**

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= event.name %></td>
   <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
   ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

`@events = Event.where("your_database_field >= ?", Date.current)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a where statement?

`@events.where("your_date_field >= ?", Date.today)`

You should set the @events in your controller, and then you can leave the code you posted as-is.

Comment: Watch out for the order of characters expressing (in)equalities.

Comment: This will only find events where the date is today's date.  "=>" is not "greater than or equal to".

Comment: Good catch, fixed!